# How to format Time Stored in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I have time in DB2 for i like this:

```
TIME
------
141412
12:30:12
12 20 12
12 12:12
1218 12
 : :
```

I want result like this:

```
TIME
------
14:14:12
12:30:12
12:20:12
12:12:12
12:18:12
20:20:20
```

How I can achieve this in DB2 (7.1) on iSeries? 
Thanks.

Comment: This is probably not what you're looking for, but the best way would have been to store it in the proper format in the first place (as a [`TIME` datatype](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_i5_54/db2/rbafzmstch2data.htm#ch2datetime)).  It will be very difficult to convert all of those different formats as you list.

Comment: If you are on the latest version of Db2 for i-series, then you should consider using the new regular-expression functions to do the data cleaning. However, after data cleaning you should implement either a correct data model (using a correctly typed column such as time or timestamp), or implement better data-validation on whatever input streams populate these string columns.